# Running Apache Dev/Test server locally

Tags: php, apache, localhost, offline-mode

Is there any way that I can set up Apache to run locally, specifically NOT connecting to the internet, so that it may serve dynamic content (PHP) over a LAN?

I'm trying to set up a development environment on my Windows XP SP3 box and gain some experience with building web PHP driven web applications. I have residential Rogers service, and it's a violation of the TOS to have a server running over that connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Umm yes. Just [download apache](http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi) and fire it up. The only way it's going to get to the outside is if you specifically open up ports in your firewall/router to let http traffic in and route it to your machine. And if you're serious about getting some experience, ditch XP and get a quality linux distro on your "development" box. You can always remote desktop or ssh to it from a windows machine if you feel more comfortable that way.

My experience has been that many hosting companies use [CentOs](http://www.centos.org/) for their client servers, so I'd recommend trying that first if the purpose is gaining useful experience.

Oh by the way, **Linux happens to be free.**

Comment: I considered this initially, and I think I feel pretty comfortable with letting my firewall do the work. I was wondering alternatively if there was anything along the lines of configuring Apache to only run on localhost (as counter-intuitive as "make a web server not serve the web" may sound). Is it really that uncommon to have a private test server like this? Or am i thinking about this the wrong way?

Comment: No, you're right. I'm running apache/php5.4/mysql on the computer I type this from with apache virtual hosts set up so I can access testing "websites" on my local machine. It's pretty normal. I'd say preferred. I'm not a windows-hater ... in fact when I started it was on XP. It's been my experience that PHP development is much more of a hassle on windows. With linux PHP "just works." Not to mention most hosting companies often use Linux because they don't want to pay Bill Gates for an IIS server license. It's generally better to learn on the same type of system you're likely to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WAMP. It installs everything you'll need to get a testing server up and running in minutes

Answer (score 0):

Using a packaged solution like [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) or [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html) will provide you with the basics for setting up an Apache web server + PHP + MySQL + the phpMyAdmin interface for working with MySQL outside of the command line.